github permission denied for user. but ssh -T github.com works
I'm so confused. I try to do ssh push to a repo and I get:
error: Permission to somerepo.git denied to jenia. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

But when I do ssh -T github.com I get:
Hi jenia! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I don't get it.
Perhaps the remote needs to give permission to push?

Yes. You need to be given explicit access to a repo to push to it.

@LeGEC It's a different access from the clone one if I remember correctly?

check the doc: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/access-permissions-on-github
